# HTML - Javascript form in form

Tags: html

```
<script>
  function(form)
  {
     form.submit();
  }
</script>

<form action="do-1" id="frm1" method="post" >
   <form action="do-2" id="frm2" method="post" >
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="test(this.form)"
   </form>
</form>
```

someone tell me how to submit frm2 by js ?

i click and it always submit frm1 :(

Do it is impossible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html), you can't nest `form` tags.

> Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested.

I doubt browsers will consistently handle nested forms intuitively in your case. From my experience by accidentally nesting form tags, IE8, for example, will not even render them properly. It causes many layout problems.

Answer (score 1):

Keep only one form tag and one `/form` close tag. As everyone says, you can not nest the form tag in html.

And make sure your input tag is closed properly.

Example:

```
<form action="get.jsp" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is completely invalid html, you can't nest forms in any version of html

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the word test after function?